# RedirectRoute in Google App Engine and url arguments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have a RESTful API like `/do/some/<action:.*>` so my app with get `<action>` and run it.

My question is, if I use `RedirectRoute` and `strict_slash=True`, will my app keep getting `<action>` as argument or will it start getting `<action>/` (notice the `/` at the end)?

EDIT: I'm using webapp2

Answer (score 1):

A RedirectRoute will issue a HTTP redirect telling the browser to go to the new URL, then the browser will make a new request at that URL.

How this is implemented is that *two* routes are created - your original route, and one for redirecting.

So, in your case, a route with `/do/some/<action:.*>/` would be created that redirects to `/do/some/<action.*>`.

However, I think your route actually will be checked first (not positive, sorry), so it would just always fire. I would modify it to not match slashes, if that's okay. Luckily, that's the default behaviour if you omit the regex, so just `/do/some/<action:>` should work!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, but I was reffering to what will be the value of ```<action>``` in my handler. Example: ```wget www.myhost.com/do/some/say_hello``` -> the value of ```action``` is ```say_hello```. Will ```wget www.myhost.com/do/some/say_hello/``` make ```<action>```'s value to be ```say_hello``` too? Or will it be ```say_hello/```?

Comment: I understand. I don't think your handler works well with the `strict_slash` action, so it will actually get the `say_hello/`. If you change your handler to `<action:>` (Which prohibits /'s in the action), it should always be `say_hello`